# SQL perform AVG after MAX

Tags: sql, oracle, join, max, average

I have two tables. `Table1`:

```
| ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | ID4 |
|-----+-----+-----+-----|
| 200 | 125 | 300 | 201 |
| 206 | 128 | 650 | 261 |
| 230 | 543 | 989 | 403 |
```

and `Table2`:

```
| ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | ID4 |  Date  | Cost |
|-----+-----+-----+-----+--------+------|
| 200 | 125 | 300 | 201 | 1/1/19 | 0.32 |
| 200 | 125 | 300 | 201 | 1/1/19 | 0.33 |
| 200 | 125 | 300 | 201 | 1/1/19 | 0.34 |
| 200 | 125 | 300 | 201 | 1/2/13 | 0.00 |
| 200 | 125 | 300 | 201 | 9/5/05 | 0.01 |
```

I am trying to `Join` `Table1` to `Table2` while filtering the outputs so only one row where `date` is at its maximum for those classifications are displayed and the average `cost` at that maximum date is also displayed. Here is my current code:

```
SELECT t1.ID1, t1.ID2, t1.ID3, t1.ID4, maxDate, avgCost
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN ( SELECT ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4, MAX(Date) as maxDate, AVG(Cost) as avgCost
FROM Table2 t2
GROUP BY ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4 ) t2
ON t2.ID1 = t1.ID1
AND t2.ID2 = t1.ID2
AND t2.ID3 = t1.ID3
AND t2.ID4 = t1.ID4
```

With the example data given above, my result looks like this:

```
| ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | ID4 |  MaxDate  | AvgCost |
|-----+-----+-----+-----+-----------+---------|
| 200 | 125 | 300 | 201 |  1/1/19   |   0.20  |
```

When it should just be looking like this

```
| ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | ID4 | MaxDate   | AvgCost |
|-----+-----+-----+-----+-----------+---------|
| 200 | 125 | 300 | 201 |   1/1/19  |   0.33  |
```

The average cost is including values where `date` is not at its maximum. I'm assuming this is due to `AVG(cost)` being executed before `Table2` is filtered with `MAX(Date)`. Here's what I've tried:

```
SELECT t1.ID1, t1.ID2, t1.ID3, t1.ID4, maxDate, avgCost
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN ( SELECT ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4, MAX(Date) as maxDate, AVG(Cost) as avgCost
FROM Table2 t2
GROUP BY ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4 ) t2
ON t2.ID1 = t1.ID1
AND t2.ID2 = t1.ID2
AND t2.ID3 = t1.ID3
AND t2.ID4 = t1.ID4
WHERE maxDate = (SELECT MAX(Date) from Table2);
```

and

```
SELECT t1.ID1, t1.ID2, t1.ID3, t1.ID4, maxDate, avgCost
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN ( SELECT ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4, MAX(Date) as maxDate, AVG(Cost) as avgCost
FROM Table2 t2
GROUP BY ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4 ) t2
ON t2.ID1 = t1.ID1
AND t2.ID2 = t1.ID2
AND t2.ID3 = t1.ID3
AND t2.ID4 = t1.ID4
WHERE maxDate = (SELECT MAX(Date) from Table2 GROUP BY ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4);
```

The first gives no results and the second results in an error, `ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row`. The rest of what I've tried is basically variations of the above, but I'm still not getting the results expected. I'm not sure how to make the `AVG` function perform only where `Date` is at its max...

Comment: in your data sample there is not the t1.ID4 values ..  why???

Comment: @scaisEdge Sorry, fixed

Comment: based on the data sample  in your table 2 you can't obatin two rows ..  are you sure the data are the same and there is not some hidden char  .. that return 2 aggreagated  rows

Comment: @scaisEdge Okay, so I've simplified the comparisons being made a little bit. The 4th ID is actually a string and the comparison is `SUBSTR(t1.ID4, 1, 5) = SUBSTR(t2.ID4, 1, 5)`. It is true that where `cost` is `0.00` in `Table2`, there are 6 chars in `ID4` while the rest only have 5. But shouldn't that be reconciled with the `SUBSTR(t2.ID4, 1, 5)`?

Comment: and you should have `0.2`and `AvgCost` result.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Look at my explanation. Part of the problem is that whenever `Cost` is `0.00` in `Table2`, it's not being counted in the `AVG(cost)` function. I'm being returned two rows when there should only be one

Comment: I already looked your explanation, but you should already need to have  one row.Consider:https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=05c1e0e1c18b040322ec37d0c699f02f

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Okay I actually fixed that. If you see the comments above, `ID4` is actually a string and I needed to compare the first 5 chars of that string. I fixed the issue by modifying my `GROUP BY` to `GROUP BY ID1, ID2, ID3, SUBSTR(ID4, 1, 5)`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of `t2` looks like this:

```
( SELECT ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4, MAX(Date) as maxDate, AVG(Cost) as avgCost
FROM Table2 t2
GROUP BY ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4 ) t2
```

Instead, to compute the average **only over the most recent date**, it should use a different aggregate function - the `LAST` function, like so:

```
( SELECT ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4, MAX(Date) as maxDate, 
         AVG(Cost) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY Date) as avgCost
FROM Table2 t2
GROUP BY ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4 ) t2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, might not be the optimal solution but you can tweek it for better performance

```
WITH MAXDATE AS (
SELECT  MAX(DATE) AS MAXDATE,
        ID1,
        ID2,
        ID3,
        ID4
FROM TABLE2
GROUP BY ID1,ID2,ID3,ID4
)
SELECT ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4, MAX(DATE), AVG(COST)
FROM TABLE1 T1 JOIN TABLE2 T2
ON T1.ID1 = T2.ID1
ON T1.ID2 = T2.ID2
ON T1.ID3 = T2.ID3
ON T1.ID4 = T2.ID4 JOIN MAXDATE T3
ON T1.ID1 = T3.ID1
ON T1.ID2 = T3.ID2
ON T1.ID3 = T3.ID3
ON T1.ID4 = T3.ID4
ON T2.DATE = T3.MAXDATE

GROUP BY T1.ID1
         T1.ID2
         T1.ID3
         T1.ID4
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
select id1, id2, id3, id4, date, avg(cost)
from (select t2.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by id1, id2, id3, id4 order by date desc) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     ) t2
where seqnum = 1
group by id1, id2, id3, id4, date;
```

The `dense_rank()` enumerates the values by date in inverse order -- with ties being counted for a single ranking.  So the most recent date has a value of `1`.  The `where seqnum = 1` then selects only the most recent date.

`table1` is only needed if you want to filter the results.  You might as well do:

```
select id1, id2, id3, id4, date, avg(cost)
from (select t2.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by id1, id2, id3, id4 order by date desc) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
      where (id1, id2, id3, id4) in (select id1, id2, id3, id4 from table1)
     ) t2
where seqnum = 1
group by id1, id2, id3, id4, date;
```

Comment: Yep, this solves it. Looked over some info for `dense_rank()` and `partition by` and it seems to make sense. Could you explain what the `where seqnum = 1` is doing?

Comment: -1 from me for using an analytic function where it's not needed. The correct solution is to use the aggregate `LAST` function - the query becomes much more efficient.